# Why is my XML reader reading every other element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I've built a very simple table that displays 4 columns and 4 rows.  When the following code is executed it displays every other element in the .xml file. It does not discriminate per table row.  It reads through without any problem and I have run xml validators so it not a syntax issue.

```
public partial class lblXmlOutput : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("Part2XMLex.xml"), settings);

        string result = "";

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement("td"))
                result += reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            txtOutput.Text = result;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because both `.Read()` and `.ReadElementContentAsString()` (the parameterless overload) move the reader to the next node.

Change your `while` condition to:

```
while (!reader.EOF)
```

Then add:

```
else reader.Read();
```

Comment: So what would your suggestion be to allow the reader to properly iterate through the table displaying the desired results?

Comment: It doesn't seem like that was the solution, just get a spinning wheel while the page attempts to load (with no success). I'm not sure if there is any other formatting needed.

Comment: I've viewed SO for solutions and implemented a variety of these fixes yet none of them seem to stop the reader from skipping elements and .EOF causes an infinite loop.

Comment: @James - I didn't notice your `if` statement at first.  You need to move the reader forward in an `else` statement.  Updated my answer.