# XmlReader sensative about whitespace between elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

The XML reader seems to be sensitive about white-space around empty elements.

If I have an empty element with no spaces (`<B />`) then the reader doesn't see it as an element.

```
public static void Main()
{
    WriteLine("No spaces around <B>.");
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(@"<Index><A>a</A><B /><C>c</C></Index>"))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name != "Index" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.Name, reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            }
        }
    }
    WriteLine();
    WriteLine("Spaces added around <B>.");
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(@"<Index><A>a</A> <B /> <C>c</C></Index>"))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name != "Index" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.Name, reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            }
        }
    }

    Read();
}
```

Printing out the `NodeType` values it looks like it does see it.  Here I'm printing our the types found in order (minus the if statement above):

```
No spaces around <B>.      Spaces added around <B>.
     Index: Element         Index: Element
         A: Element             A: Element
          : Text                 : Text
         A: EndElement          A: EndElement
         B: Element              : Whitespace
         C: Element             B: Element
          : Text                 : Whitespace
         C: EndElement          C: Element
     Index: EndElement           : Text
                                C: EndElement
                            Index: EndElement
```

The problem seems to be with the statement:

```
reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
```

If I remove that statement then I get `B` appearing again.  I thought that it might be something to do with that method moving the `reader` to the next node (?) but I can't seem to prove that, or work around it.

How should I handle empty nodes with the `XmlReader`?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [XmlReader - problem reading xml file with no newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7196468/3744182) and [Why is my XML reader reading every other element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10038193/3744182).

Comment: And also [c# XMLReader skips nodes after using ReadElementContentAs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991311/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `ReadElementContentAsString` advances the reader past the end of `</A>`, so that it is positioned on the empty element `<B />` in the version without spaces and the text node  in the version with spaces. The control the proceeds to the `reader.Read()` statement-expression in the head of the `while` loop, which advances the reader past that, effectively skipping it. So you need to modify the logic so that `reader.Read()` is not called in the head of your loop if `ReadElementContentAsString` is called in the body.